# To achieve authentication using two or more schemes and retrieve the IsAuthenticated status

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, cookies, authorization

I have two schemes as follows:

```
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(option =>
{
    option.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie(option => // Admins' Scheme
{
    option.LoginPath = new PathString("/admin/auth/login");
    option.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    option.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/");
}).AddCookie("user", option => // Users' Scheme
{
    option.LoginPath = new PathString("/");
    option.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    option.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/");
});
```

There are two ways to access the login functionality for users: admin and ordinary users.

For admins:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(RequestAuthLoginUsersServiceDto req)
    {
        var login = _userFacade.AuthLoginUsersService.Execute(req);
        if (login != null)
        {
            if (login.IsSuccess)
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim>() {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,login.Data.IdUser.ToString()),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email,req.Email),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,login.Data.Nickname),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,login.Data.Role),
                };

                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                var propertise = new AuthenticationProperties()
                {
                    IsPersistent = true,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1),
                };
                _userLoginLogFacade.PostUserLoginLogService.Execute(new RequestPostUserLoginLogServiceDto
                {
                    UsersId = login.Data.IdUser,
                    IP = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(),
                });
                HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal, propertise);
            }
        }
        return Json(login);
    }
```

user:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(RequestAuthLoginUsersServiceDto req)
        {
        var login = _userFacade.AuthLoginUsersService.Execute(req);
        if (login != null)
        {
            if (login.IsSuccess)
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim>() {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,login.Data.IdUser.ToString()),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email,req.Email),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,login.Data.Nickname),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,login.Data.Role),
                };

                // var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "user");
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                var propertise = new AuthenticationProperties()
                {
                    IsPersistent = true,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1),
                };
                _userLoginLogFacade.PostUserLoginLogService.Execute(new RequestPostUserLoginLogServiceDto
                {
                    UsersId = login.Data.IdUser,
                    IP = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(),
                });
                HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                    "user",
                    principal,
                    propertise);
            }
        }
```

The problem is that when a user logs in, "User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" returns "false". However, when an admin logs in, the same code returns "true". It is important to note that if I use "[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "user")]", the code returns "true" for the user. However, for the default mode (admin way), the "[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "user")]" is not needed.

Comment: I would perhaps rename the admin cookie handler to "admin" instead of }).AddCookie(option => // Admins' Scheme. just to ensure that you don't have any scheme confusion. And just to make the code more consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it would be better for me to provide a brief explanation about my main problem and question.

Why did I use two schemes in the following code? Based on my structure, I have two main areas: Admin and User areas. I want to have two login paths so that when either an admin or a user signs out, the system can redirect them to their respective paths.

I have realized that it is not necessary to log in with two schemes, but it is necessary to have them (schemes) in place. Based on my experiences:

1. You need to log in with the same scheme (CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).
2. However, you need to differentiate each controller based on the scheme and roles to be redirected to the desired page (loginPaths). Based on this distinction, you will need to refresh (reload) your page to trigger your authorization system.

The revised blocks are as follows:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(RequestAuthLoginUsersServiceDto req)
    {
        var login = _userFacade.AuthLoginUsersService.Execute(req);
        if (login != null)
        {
            if (login.IsSuccess)
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim>() {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,login.Data.IdUser.ToString()),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email,req.Email),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,login.Data.Nickname),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,login.Data.Role),
                };

                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                var propertise = new AuthenticationProperties()
                {
                    IsPersistent = true,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1),
                };
                _userLoginLogFacade.PostUserLoginLogService.Execute(new RequestPostUserLoginLogServiceDto
                {
                    UsersId = login.Data.IdUser,
                    IP = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(),
                });
                HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal, propertise);
            }
        }
        return Json(login);
    }
```

and to log out:

```
        public IActionResult Logout()
    {
        HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        string currentUrl = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString(); // Get the current URL
        return Redirect(currentUrl);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One **possible** issue is that right now:

```
   option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
```

That means that only this admin handler will validate incoming requests and the question is if the auth cookie issued by the user cookie handler, can be decoded by the handler for the admin cookies?

I recently digged into this, and the issued cookies can only be read by the same handler that issued the cookies in the first place. This is because the "purpose" string used when protecting the cookies includes the "scheme" name. like

```
Performing protect operation to key {...} with purposes (
  - 'C:\code\Data Protection API - Demo project\Data Protection API - Start project\',
  - 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware', 
  - 'cookie', 
  - 'v2').
```

I would also set the log level to verbose/trace to see what the auth system says.

Why do you need two cookie handlers? I would think one is enough and you include a claim (role?) into the identity, to allow you do keep users appart.

You can provide different redirect after signin values by setting the authentication properties:

```
var prop = new AuthenticationProperties()
{
    RedirectUri = loginCredentials.ReturnUrl,    //Where to redirect to after login
    Items =
    {
        { "IpAddress", "192.168.0.3" },
        { "ComputerName", "MyComputer" },
        { "ApiKey", "Summer2023" }
    }
}; 
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(scheme: "cookie", principal: principal, properties: prop);
```

The other option is to the hook into the AddCookie event handlers, and this one could be useful.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationevents.onredirecttologin?view=aspnetcore-8.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-authentication-cookies-cookieauthenticationevents-onredirecttologin

btw, I got some blog post about troubleshooting auth issues at https://nestenius.se/

Comment: Actually, I added two cookies because I have two different "loginPath" values, one for ordinary users and the other for admins. What other recommendations do you have?

Comment: do you mean the path when they are challenged (path to the login form?) or path after login? I added some code to my answer.

Comment: I would use one handler, and would redirect to the normal user login page. That page could perhap, by looking at the returnUrl /user/login?ReturnUrl=%2FSecure   , redirect the user to the admin login page if the user looks to be an admin.

Comment: When the user signs out, the line "option.LoginPath" in the program.cs file is automatically executed. How do you inform the system about the type of user who is signing out? otherwise, we set the "login path" manually.

Comment: When you signout the user using SignOutAsync, you can redirect the user to whatever page you want. You could simply create a separate cookie for admin users, like "IsAdmin" that can give you a hint where to redirect him to. Or you hook into the this event https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationevents.onredirecttoreturnurl?view=aspnetcore-8.0